# Predicting failure (e.g. from weibull) of part that has already survived a certain time

Tags: cumulative-distribution-function, weibull-distribution

Simple question, but I'm overthinking it.

Say that I already have a cumulative failure distribution, cdf, (Weibull, but let's just assume any type of distribution) calculated from historical part data.
Now I have a specific part that has already lived to time t1.  How do I calculate that part's probability of failure, starting at this point, t2, t3 and beyond?

I tried  just scaling it based on the original distribution.
failure_fract = (cdf(t2) - cdf(t1)/(1 - cdf(t1))

The endpoints seem correct:

- at t=t1, the failure fract is 0 (we know each part is alive),
- at a large time t, the original cdf would be 1, so the ratio becomes 1.

However, when I throw in some Weibull numbers and look at the results, it just seems wrong.  The part that has already survived the longest has a bigger chance of living to t2 from its current point than the part that is much younger.

I assume I am approaching it wrong.  A colleague mentioned Bayesean updating, but that doesn't seem right to me either.

Comment: When a part has survived a long time, that can be evidence that it's a very good part, so why shouldn't it have a longer expected remaining lifetime?  If the Weibull distribution didn't have this characteristic there nevertheless would *have* to be some sufficiently heavy-tailed distribution that did.  BTW, your scaling (correctly) defines a *truncated* distribution.

Comment: Thanks!  That is just what I needed.

Comment: The [Wikipedia article on the Weibulll distribution family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution#Standard_parameterization) has a good account of this.  The Weibull shape parameter determines whether the hazard ratio decreases or increases over time, showing that this family of waiting time distributions can model a variety of such phenomena.